# Intellij IDEA - stop gradle run tool window from filtering console logs?

Tags: intellij-idea

I find that when I'm running a failing Gradle task from within IDEA, the "Run" tool window automatically selects the most recent "node" in the tool window, which filters out all the console logs except from that "node" - IDEA tries help by showing only the logs relating to the failing task.

The problem is that the console output of just the last task *never* shows useful output.
It doesn't show the exception that caused the failure, and it doesn't show any logs leading up to the failure.

For example, when running a `JavaExec` task, by default IDEA shows this when the task ends:
[image]

In order to see the info that's actually relevant to debugging the issue, I need to manually select a node higher in the tree:
[image]

**The question:**

Is there any way to tell IDEA to automatically select the "task node" for a failing Gradle task (which usually contains the usable information), instead of the "command" node which almost never shows useful information?

---

IntelliJ: 2022.1.3
Gradle: 7.4.1

Comment: `Is there any way to tell IDEA to automatically select the "task node" for a failing Gradle tas` There is no such option. Thank you for [filling a request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-297834).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment from Andrey - there is no such option for IDEA 2022.1.